# Create div with data attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating div the following way

```
$('<div/>', {
    "class" : 'draggable player' + player + ' unit unit' + unit
})
```

And I can't find what other properties I can assign to it the same way I assign class. especially if I can assign `data` or `attr`?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

According to the [`jQuery()`function documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2) (alias of `$()`), you can define attributes, events, and methods within that second parameter.

So yes, anything you’d define using [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) is fair game. That includes “data-whatever” *attributes* (which are oddly accessible via `$elem.data('whatever')`), however they will not be saved to [`jQuery.data`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) like any variables defined via [`$elem.data('name', 'value')`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) (at least until you call `$elem.data('whatever')` – see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/#entry-longdesc-1).

So to clarify:

```
var $elem = jQuery('<div/>', { 'data-test': "Testing" });
```

will create this element, and return a jQuery object containing it:

```
<div data-test="Testing"></div>
```

From there, you will be able to do:

```
jQuery.data($elem[0], 'test'); // => undefined
$elem.data('test');            // => "Testing"
jQuery.data($elem[0], 'test'); // => "Testing"
```

Of course, `$elem.attr('data-test')` will also work.

Comment: I guess it's rather `elem` than `$elem`. Speaking PHP? ;)

Comment: Prefixing JS variables with `$` is a pretty common practice for identifying jQuery objects.

Comment: ah - nice to know, thanks. Shouldn't have been offensive anyways =)

Comment: For more complex data objects: `jQuery('<div/>', { 'data': {'test': "Testing", 'another-test': {a:1, b:2} }})`

Answer (score 12):

You can assign any attributes you want:

```
$('<div/>', {
    "class" : 'draggable player' + player + ' unit unit' + unit,
    "data-info": 'Anything you want',
    "even-non-validating-attributes": 'ANYTHING!!'
});
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vCaym/